# Icon left of multi-line heading

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to display an icon (font awesome) to the left of a heading, which currently works when the heading is on a single line, but the alignment gets messed up when the heading goes onto a second line.

What it currently looks like:

[image: Bad title]

What I want:

[image: Good title]

Here's the simplest form of what I have ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8k79wqd/)):

```
<div>
  <h1><i class="fa fa-file-text fa-fw fa-lg"></i>Multi-line Title</h1>
</div>
```

I've tried separating the icon into a separate `h1`, then float or inline display each of those, but because it's multi-line text none of that has worked.

What's a clean way to get this alignment I'm looking for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A little late to the party, but if anyone else is having the same issue - this is an easy fix with CSS Flexbox (which is a new...ish style, but by this point is pretty robustly supported).

(Note for code below: You can wrap the `<i>` in a `<div>`, or something else if necessary, but I would advise against including a second `<h1>` tag as that could cause SEO issues. Basically, you need the .wrapper class with two children - one as the icon (or a div containing the icon), and one as the header.)

First, the new HTML:

```
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-file-text fa-fw fa-lg"></i>
  <h1>Multi-line Title</h1>
</div>
```

And the new CSS:

```
div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Note: `align-items: center;` sets vertical alignment. This can also be flex-start (top-aligned) or flex-end (bottom-aligned) as desired.

Answer (score 3):

Add this

```
div h1 {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
padding-left: 55px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

div h1 i {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -10px; // half height of icon
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8k79wqd/5/)

Comment: Is there any way to make the vertical positioning adapt nicely to whether the heading is 1 or 2 lines? It ends up too high for the 1-line headings.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, Using absolute positioning on the icon solves the problem. Besides, adjust it's top margin to align with the title text.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0fadtcm7/

```
div h1 i {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -55px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
div h1 {
    padding-left: 55px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just found an easier way to solve this.

**HTML:**

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-file-text fa-fw fa-lg"></i>
  </h1>
  <h1>Multi-line Title</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
div {
  width: 225px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

.icon {
  display: inline;
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 55%;
}
```

The most important point is to change the width to a suitable value.

Working JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/hfqoj5d9/